# How do I interpret the following mod_rewrite conditions?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite conditions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
```

I have read the Apache mod_rewrite manual however am having difficulty interpreting the above.

1. I know that the condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means if the requested file name is missing
2. The condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means if the requested directory is missing.
3. I have no idea what `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)` means

My understanding is rules proceeding conditions are applied if the conditions are evaluated true but the rule I have proceeding the conditions is `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`

As I don't know what Point 3 refers to yet, would I be correct to interpret that if Point 1 evaluates to be true i.e. if the request file is missing AND Point 2 i.e. if the request directory is missing then do `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`

**EDIT**

Having dug around a fair bit further it appears that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` mean when anything that is not a file or directory AND not that they are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line is saying "the requested URI doesn't end with one of the listed suffixes." (Strictly speaking, as KingCrunch pointed out, it checks whether one of the suffixes is in the string at all, whether at the end or in the middle.)

Rules **following** conditions are applied if the conditions are true; rules preceding the conditions are separate and have no connection to the conditions.

You are correct in that if condition 1 and condition 2 and condition 3 all evaluate to true, then the rule following will be executed.

To break down that last regular expression:

The `!` means not, i.e., if REQUEST_URI does not match the expression;

`.*` means any characters zero or more times;

`\.` means a period (or full-stop) -- this is escaped with a backslash because otherwise `.` means any character;

`(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)` means one of the strings separated by the vertical bar `|`, that is, "`ico` or `gif` or `jpg` etc."

If the regular expression had been written ending with `$` (the end-of-string marker) then there could be no characters after the suffix; as written now, any characters may follow.

So the RewriteCond is checking if REQUEST_URI does not match some characters, followed by a period, followed by one of the file type suffixes listed. If it does not, then the condition evaluates to true.

Comment: I didn't quite follow what you meant by `it checks whether one of the suffixes is in the string at all, whether in the end or the middle.` Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Edited. I hope that explanation makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the link to any good Regular Expression tutorials, but if you search the internet there's a plethora of them out there. A regular myriad of plethoras, in fact.

Comment: That was extremely helpful. The one thing I am still confused about how do the directives `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` work. For example if I have the URI `www.domain.com/directory1/filename1.whatever` what is it validating?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey In that case `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is validating `/directory1/filename1.whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

The last condition means "When `REQUEST_URI` does not contain [1] one of 'ico', 'gif', 'jpg' (and so on)". When all three rules evaluates to `true`, the (not shown) `RewriteRule` is applied.

[1] Which is kind of ... incomplete, because it *should* say "not end in", but it doesn't. But this is a different point :)

Comment: Thanks KingCrunch. What do you mean by `should say "ends in"?` I also thought there was not need to escape meta characters e.g `.` with` \.` in the example `.*\.`

Comment: "It should end" (in fact "should _not_ end". Missed the `!` first ;)), because the current condition also matches for example `my.jpg.php`, what may or may not be expected/wanted. And `.` in regular expressions mean "any character", so if you want a literal `.` it must of course be escaped.